# Stopping the LAG function from incrementing

Tags: sql-server

I would like my output to look like this.

Is there any way  you can use the Lag function to do this?

```
ID1     Column1 

NULL      NULL 
NULL      NULL 
2017      2017
NULL      2017
NULL      2017
NULL      2017
NULL      2017 
NULL      NULL 
NULL      NULL     
2048      2048
NULL      2048
NULL      2048
2098      2098
NULL      2098
NULL      2098
NULL      2098
```

Comment: can you elaborate? There isn't enough sample data or expected results here.

Comment: If column 2 is the desired result then totally unclear how you want that calculated based on column 1. Why does the group of 2017s become NULL? What column denotes the order?

Comment: I would like to bring down the value of Column1 in Column2 until I obtain a new value in Column1 and repeat the process.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are trying to simulate `LAST_VALUE` with `IGNORE NULLS`.

In which case your desired results are not correct.

You can do ([demo - borrows scsimon's data](http://rextester.com/QOYR63338))

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,Column1
    ,0 + LEFT(MAX(ID_Column1) OVER (ORDER BY ID),10) AS LagID
    ,0 + RIGHT(MAX(ID_Column1) OVER (ORDER BY ID),10) AS LagColumn1
FROM
    @Table t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (FORMAT(ID,'D10') + FORMAT(Column1,'D10'))) V(ID_Column1);
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there any way to do this without using an alias?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need another column that shows the order... otherwise the `LEAD` and `LAG` could get out of sync. With that being said, you would need to look at all previous rows unbounded until you hit a `NULL`, Here is a simple way with a sub-query

```
declare @table table (ID int identity(1,1), Column1 int)
insert into @table
values
(NULL),
(NULL),
(2017),
(NULL),
(NULL),
(NULL),
(2048),
(NULL),
(NULL),
(NULL),
(NULL),
(2098)


SELECT
    ID
    ,Column1
    ,ISNULL(Column1, (SELECT TOP 1 Column1 FROM @Table WHERE ID < t.ID AND Column1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID DESC)) as Column2
FROM
    @Table t
```

**RETURNS**

```
+----+---------+---------+
| ID | Column1 | Column2 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 | NULL    | NULL    |
|  2 | NULL    | NULL    |
|  3 | 2017    | 2017    |
|  4 | NULL    | 2017    |
|  5 | NULL    | 2017    |
|  6 | NULL    | 2017    |
|  7 | 2048    | 2048    |
|  8 | NULL    | 2048    |
|  9 | NULL    | 2048    |
| 10 | NULL    | 2048    |
| 11 | NULL    | 2048    |
| 12 | 2098    | 2098    |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it is still incrementing by 1 in Column1.  Is there anyway to duplicate a row where the value simply stays the same throughout thousands of rows?

Comment: What do you mean it's incrementing by 1 in Column1? What would your expected results be? You stated you wanted the value from Column1 until you hit a new non-null value. that's exactly what this does.

Comment: @AllisonCoder check the test here http://rextester.com/MCDCX97880  I'm not sure what you are doing wrong. My code runs as expected.

Comment: Yes, it works.  Is there any way to reference the "WHERE ID < t.ID" without using "t" as an alias.  I ask because this is causing some issues in my code.

Comment: How's that possible? It's just a table alias. How about you post your code to the original question.

Comment: Thank you for your help scsimon.  I have posted my original code.

Comment: @AllisonCoder posted it where? I don't see any edit to the question.

Comment: I have put my code at the very top of the question. Thank you.